# track the incoming call action

Tags: android, call, callstack

I know this is a asked question. By using broadcast receiver and using 
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE

in receiver tag, you can know the actions of a phone. But how can I identify whether it is an incoming call or a outgoing call?

here is my code

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    this.context = context ;
    System.out.println(":::called onReceiver:::");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
private final PhoneStateListener phoneCallListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            switch(state)
            {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                 isRinging = true;
                 break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                 if (isRinging) 
                 {
                     hasAttended = true ;
                     isRinging = false;
                 } 
                 break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                 if (hasAttended)
                 {
                     isCallEnded = true ;
                     hasAttended = false;
                 }
                 break;
            }
            if(isCallEnded)
            {
                isCallEnded=false;
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
                callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```

here each time a phoneCallListener object is created and increases the calling rate of onCallStateChanged by one each time..

Comment: @juli-Have you resolved this problem..??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid yep ... the code works .. but I created a singleton class for phoneStateListener to get the same instance and set boolean flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/) is a handy tutorial that uses both broadcast receiver and using android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE that creates different toasts to appear depending on the calls state. When you get this working you will be able to manipulate the code to do what you want when a call is either incoming or outgoing

First your class must `extend BroadcastReceiver`

Next you have to create a method that will listen to the phones state... `PhoneStateListener` which will listen to when the Phone state changes

Then do a simple `switch case` to catch the call depending on if it is an incoming call or an outgoing call

EDIT

All you need to do is write some code to check if the previous state was 'ringing'. If the current state is idle and the previous state was ringing, they cancelled/missed the call. If the current state is offhook and the previous state was ringing, they answered the call.

```
switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING");
             wasRinging = true;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

             if (!wasRinging) {
                 // Start your new activity
             } else {
                 // Cancel your old activity
             }

             // this should be the last piece of code before the break
             wasRinging = true;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
             // this should be the last piece of code before the break
             wasRinging = true;
             break;
    }
```

Comment: hi..i specifically want at what instance you can say it as a incoming call (not missed call).ie., if state=TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING then the call is incoming, but how to determine whether the call is attended or missed. I m aiming to show a popup according to the results

Comment: i have add more code to the answer which should check if the call was answered or missed... you can simply add a toast to the code which will pop-up depending on what happened and put what ever information into the toast you want

Comment: thanks ..it worked..I have overriden onCallStateChanged() . But this method is called many times...(nearly nine times) . can you explain why?

Comment: well i would have to see the code and what you are exactly doing to explain it properly.... but onCallStateChanged() is working with BroadcastReceiver. so onCallStateChanged() will always get called whenever call state get changed. so if you are going by the code i have added above , we have three call states
..TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE..TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK..TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING.. so really there should only three calls not nine, but i cannot say why it is being called nine times without looking at your code.. try debugging to see how many times its called

Comment: and when i say "try debugging to see how many times its called", i mean see how many times the method onCallStateChanged() is being called, because if it is called 3 times that would be 3x3=9 giving you the 9 you are referring to

Comment: hi..i think i figured out the problem..it is when we register a listener each time an object is created and listener of the previous object remains . so each time when the phone state changes the number of time the onCallStateChanged method called increase by one..what shall I do ..I cannot post my code in this comment box

Comment: just edit your question and insert your code in the question then i can have a look at it